# Dhcp Classless Static Routes hook error

Tags: ubuntu, debian, dhcp

I have a dhcp server that hands network information to vms of mine. It works fine for centos6,7 , and debian 7 clients. However it fails for Debian 8 and Ubuntu 16.04 clients.

For the ones where it does not work, it gets the lease without issue, but it fails to add the default gateway / route so the network is unreachable.

Example routing table of a not working vm: https://www.evernote.com/l/AECKuYFTQKRDJa45StPgrM96XzF-vUX8OT0

I did find this error in the hook for Classless Static Routes on the ubuntu vm: https://www.evernote.com/l/AEBqVJ4qMjlOzo58_XLVG528yKLuIzFYFTQ

If I manually add the route it works, but dhcp does not add it itself.

Any ideas of how to fix this so the network is usable?

Answer (score -1):

Actually looks like I solved this problem myself thanks to https://www.mail-archive.com/debian-bugs-dist%40lists.debian.org/msg1358149.html .

The solution was to remove the option rfc3442-classless-static-routes from the dhcpd.conf file on the dhcp server. Routes then correctly added for the ones that were not working and continued working for the ones that did before.